# When is symplectic pullback bundle trivial

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Suppose $x : S \to M$ is a smooth map, where $M$ is a symplectic manifold and $S$ is a Riemann surface. Consider the pullback bundle $x^*TM \to S$. When is this bundle trivial (as symplectic vector bundle)? If $S$ has non-empty boundary then the answer is "always". But for instance if $S$ is a sphere then it is not always trivial. What is the obstruction in general? And how does one check whether a given bundle is trivial?

Answer (score 1):

A symplectic vector bundle has a contractible family of complex structures on it, so a symplectic vector bundle is essentially a complex vector bundle. In particular then, you want to look at the first Chern class of the bundle.

Comment: Is the first Chern class being 0 a sufficient condition for triviality?

Comment: @Todd: yes, as long as $S$ is a Riemann surface. If $S$ is higher dimensional, the first Chern class vanishing is no longer sufficient.
Ask a new question if you need an explanation for this. I don't have room in this comment box to explain it. (Or just look in Milnor & Stasheff)